# MS Edge: How to get drop-down list of "Read aloud" voices?

Tags: microsoft-edge

In MS Edge, if you right-click on some text, the context menu includes "Read aloud". If you select that, Edge will read the page to you. You can then change the voice and play it back with the play button at the center above the browser content window, as seen in this display image:

[image]

I want to get the list of available voices. It doesn't appear to be available in DevTools because the drop-down box is not in the content area of the browser.

If there were a couple dozen voices, I could get the list by scrolling it and collecting display images of the box. But there are hundreds of voices, so that would take forever.

How can I get that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually find the list in the **Preferences** file under your profile folder (like C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default)

Then, search for `voice_name` and `voiceName`, and you can find over 300 results with the name "Online". But to those who don't have "Online" in their names, I'm afraid you'll have to collect them by yourself because they are not included in the local file.

Answer (score 0):

I'm accepting Kendrick's answer because it led me to most of the information I'm seeking, although some of his details didn't work for me. This answer gives my results from following his lead.

I don't have a folder `C:\Users\Administrator\`, but if "Administrator" is supposed to mean the user who is admin, I have that and have the file `C:\Users\<admin>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Preferences` (no extension). I opened it in Notepad++ and it has only one occurrence of "voice", which is `"voiceURI\":\` followed by the name of the last voice I used. That name includes "English" and I searched for that to see if there are other voice names in the file, but there aren't.

I then did a search in Notepad++ in the folder `C:\Users\<admin>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge` for "voice" and found there were a lot of occurrences in the file `C:\Users\Hal\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Secure Preferences` (no extension). In that file, I found and parsed out two lists of voices, 23 voices labeled with `voice_name` and 301 voices labeled with `voiceName`. With some redundancy between the two lists, they identify 308 unique voices.

I went back to Edge, opened the language drop-down box, and manually counted that it lists 312 voices.

I can't be completely sure that all the voices listed in the file `Secure Preferences` correspond to voices in the list in Edge. If they do, then the voices listed in the file account for all but four of the voices in Edge.

So it appears that I have obtained a pretty good, but somewhat incomplete list.

Thank you Kendrick for pointing me in the right direction.